# How to optimally do group by in MongoDB/PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, group-by

I have an optimalization problem with MongoDB. In Mongo I have data of cars GPS positions in a collection on different time.
I want to display only the newest position of each cars. How to optimize this code? This code works but it's to slow for many cars. I receive id_cars from other PostgreSQL database from another system.

Code is here:

```
<?php
        $resultDB=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id_cars FROM cars");
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultDB)){
            $filter=['carID' => intval($row["id_cars"])];
            $options=[
                'limit'=>1,
                'sort'=>[
                    'time'=>-1
                ],
                'projection'=>['carID' =>1, 'carID'=>1, 'lat'=>1, 'lon'=>1]
            ];
            
            $query=new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
            if ($cursor =$manager->executeQuery("$dbMongoDbName.ship_data", $query)){
                 $iterator = new IteratorIterator($cursor);
                $iterator->rewind();
                if ($iterator->valid()) {
                    $document = $iterator->current();
                    $result=json_decode(json_encode($document), true);
                    
                    echo $result['carID'].": ".$result['lat']." - ".$result['lon'];
                }
            }
        }
?>
```